# How to use a custom serde deserializer for chrono timestamps?

Tags: rust, serde, rust-chrono

I'm trying to parse JSON into a struct which has a `chrono::DateTime` field. The JSON has the timestamps saved in a custom format that I wrote a deserializer for.

How do I connect the two and get it working using `#[serde(deserialize_with)]`?

I'm using `NaiveDateTime` for simpler code

```rust
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;
use serde::Deserialize;
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::NaiveDateTime;

fn from_timestamp(time: &String) -> NaiveDateTime {
    NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").unwrap()
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyJson {
    name: String,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "from_timestamp")]
    timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
}

fn main() {
    let result: MyJson =
        serde_json::from_str(r#"{"name": "asdf", "timestamp": "2019-08-15T17:41:18.106108"}"#)
            .unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

I'm getting three different compile errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:10
   |
11 | #[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found type parameter
   |
   = note: expected type `&std::string::String`
              found type `__D`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:10
   |
11 | #[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^-
   |          |         |
   |          |         this match expression has type `chrono::NaiveDateTime`
   |          expected struct `chrono::NaiveDateTime`, found enum `std::result::Result`
   |          in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: expected type `chrono::NaiveDateTime`
              found type `std::result::Result<_, _>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:10
   |
11 | #[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^-
   |          |         |
   |          |         this match expression has type `chrono::NaiveDateTime`
   |          expected struct `chrono::NaiveDateTime`, found enum `std::result::Result`
   |          in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: expected type `chrono::NaiveDateTime`
              found type `std::result::Result<_, _>`
```

I'm pretty sure the `from_timestamp` function is returning a `DateTime` struct and not a `Result`, so I don't know what "expected struct `chrono::NaiveDateTime`, found enum `std::result::Result`" may mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is rather involved, but the following works:

```rust
use chrono::NaiveDateTime;
use serde::de;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::fmt;

struct NaiveDateTimeVisitor;

impl<'de> de::Visitor<'de> for NaiveDateTimeVisitor {
    type Value = NaiveDateTime;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(formatter, "a string represents chrono::NaiveDateTime")
    }

    fn visit_str<E>(self, s: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
    where
        E: de::Error,
    {
        match NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f") {
            Ok(t) => Ok(t),
            Err(_) => Err(de::Error::invalid_value(de::Unexpected::Str(s), &self)),
        }
    }
}

fn from_timestamp<'de, D>(d: D) -> Result<NaiveDateTime, D::Error>
where
    D: de::Deserializer<'de>,
{
    d.deserialize_str(NaiveDateTimeVisitor)
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyJson {
    name: String,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "from_timestamp")]
    timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
}

fn main() {
    let result: MyJson =
        serde_json::from_str(r#"{"name": "asdf", "timestamp": "2019-08-15T17:41:18.106108"}"#)
            .unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So the problem with my implementation was not matching the expected function signature exactly? (`fn from_timestamp<'de, D>(d: D) -> Result<NaiveDateTime, D::Error> where D: de::Deserializer<'de>,`)

Comment: That's part of the problem, yes. But it is just the glue. You may notice that the real meat is in the implementation of a visitor trait. This is how the customized serializer / deserializer works in serde.

Answer (score 15):

While @edwardw's answer is technically correct it IMHO contains too much boilerplate.

[`NaiveDataTime`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.7/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDateTime.html) implements [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) which means you can write a reusable generic deserializer function.

A convoluted example - did add the `age` field (`u8`) represented as string in the JSON. Just to demonstrate that you can use it for anything that implements `FromStr`.

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::str::FromStr;

use chrono::NaiveDateTime;
use serde::{de, Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyJson {
    name: String,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_from_str")]
    timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_from_str")]
    age: u8,
}

// You can use this deserializer for any type that implements FromStr
// and the FromStr::Err implements Display
fn deserialize_from_str<'de, S, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<S, D::Error>
where
    S: FromStr,      // Required for S::from_str...
    S::Err: Display, // Required for .map_err(de::Error::custom)
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let s: String = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    S::from_str(&s).map_err(de::Error::custom)
}

fn main() {
    let result: MyJson = serde_json::from_str(
        r#"{"name": "asdf", "timestamp": "2019-08-15T17:41:18.106108", "age": "11"}"#,
    )
    .unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

It's even easier if you want to specify format (use `NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str`):

```rust
use chrono::NaiveDateTime;
use serde::{de, Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyJson {
    name: String,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "naive_date_time_from_str")]
    timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
}

fn naive_date_time_from_str<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<NaiveDateTime, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let s: String = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(&s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").map_err(de::Error::custom)
}

fn main() {
    let result: MyJson =
        serde_json::from_str(r#"{"name": "asdf", "timestamp": "2019-08-15T17:41:18.106108"}"#)
            .unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

[`#[serde(deserialize_with = "path")]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with) documentation:

> Deserialize this field using a function that is different from its implementation of `Deserialize`. The given function must be callable as `fn<'de, D>(D) -> Result<T, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de>`, although it may also be generic over `T`. Fields used with `deserialize_with` are not required to implement `Deserialize`.